# SailsJS - Many to Many relationship

Tags: orm, sails.js, sails-mongo

I've gone through the documentation a few times and am not certain on how to approach this inside Sails so looking for assistance.

I have Programmer, Project, and Feedback.

I want to link them so that Feedback can be submitted for a Programmer for a specific Project. (e.g. "He was great!")

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Just put Project relation (model:) to Feedback and Project already have relation to Programmer. If this is not your case, please share your model code so I can examine your situation better

Answer (score 0):

Project and Programmer have a many-to-many relationship. Programmer has a one-to-many relationship to Feedback.
Project has a one-to-many relationship to Feedback.

Just put them in all the 3 models following the direction/order like stated above.